# Trying to use seek and skip, but md5 is different

Tags: linux, dd, hashsum

I ran into an unexpected behavior when using `dd`.

I write this to `myfile`:

```
root@io-generator-app-0:/# dd if=/dev/urandom skip=10 of=/tmp/myfile bs=4k
```

Then using `skip` option again to write it to some other folder:

```
root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# dd of=/media/bla skip=10 if=/tmp/myfile
```

Then reading it from `bla` with `seek` option:

```
root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# dd if=/media/bla seek=10 of=/tmp/myfile2
```

Now I want to compare both and for some reason they are different:

```
root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# hash1=`md5sum /tmp/myfile | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d ' '`
root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# hash2=`md5sum /tmp/myfile2 | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d ' '`
```

Hash is different:

```
root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# echo $hash1
bd7b383b1f70a050b3bdd3f2322630d9/tmp/myfile
root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# echo $hash2
7f286c7d6e10bdf530e60c52e4463ca2/tmp/myfile2
```

Any helpers, please? :)

Comment: You might use [cmp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cmp.1.html) to compare files, or [diff(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) if they are textual. You could use [od(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) to inspect files. You should read [dd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html)

Comment: `skip` skips in the _input_ before reading. `seek` seeks in the _output_ before writing. The first 10 blocks of the files will be different. The (logical) file sizes should also be different.

Comment: You could post an ls -l of the files. Your first command does not have a `count` option, so it probably ran until /tmp was full, or urandom ran out of entropy. Your second command skips 10 blocks without specifying a `bs`. Your third command seeks without a `bs`. As @Kusalananda points out, myfile has 5120 bytes of urandom data at the front, but myfile2 has 5120 bytes of nulls.

Comment: Now it works:
root@io-generator-app-0:/# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/myfile_1 bs=4k count=100

Using skip and write it to media/bla other folder (when using skip we must add bs, so it will skip from [skip*bs])

root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# dd if=/tmp/myfile_1 of=/media/bla seek=10 bs=4k oflag=direct

Then reading it from reduxio with seek (when using seek we also must add bs, so it will seek from [skip*bs])

root@io-generator-app-0:/tmp# dd if=/media/reduxio skip=10 of=/tmp/myfile_2 bs=4k count= 100